# Multiple SQL statements in one Activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, query, sql, activities

We have to check in our transaction database to see if the product is bought. We get the data like:
DB1

| key | product_1 | Product_2 | product_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 123456789 | 789456456 | 456789132 |
| 123 | 487462538 | 487454521 | 215650255 |
| 487 | 474414744 | 012345698 | 123054045 |

And this is how the transaction table looks like:
DB2

| order | key | Product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00111 | 111 | 123456789 |
| 00111 | 111 | 789456456 |
| 00112 | 123 | 215650255 |

And to know if the customer bought the product we want to have a sendable data extension that has the following structure:

| key | product_1 | bought_1 | product_2 | bought_2 | product_3 | bought_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 123456789 | 1 | 789456456 | 1 | 456789132 |  |
| 123 | 487462538 |  | 487454521 |  | 215650255 | 1 |
| 487 | 474414744 |  | 012345698 |  | 123054045 |  |

Now I have the following query:

```sql
SELECT 
c.key
, c.PRODUCT_1
, c.PRODUCT_2
, c.PRODUCT_3
, '1' as bought_1
FROM DB1 c
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 
  b.Order 
  FROM DB2 b 
  WHERE c.key = b.key 
  AND c.PRODUCT_1 = b.PRODUCT
)
```

Is there a better or more effective way to also fill in bought_2 and bought_3 instead of running three activities? Or is there a better query that can help me with this problem? Maybe AMPscript, but prefer this option as shown above, to know if they bought a product - then we skip other e-mails if they didn't buy specific products.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is DB2 just a normalized version of DB1?

Comment: @AdamSpriggs DB2 are all transaction lines and DB1 is a DE that is ready for sending, but i need to know if they bought a product, so have to check DB2 to see if they bought it. Key field in DB2 is order, key and product. Key fields in DB1 is just the key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a fan of denormalizing product data into numbered columns.  It makes everything more difficult, especially in SFMC where there are limited options for pivoting the data.

> Tall and skinny tables are better than short and fat ones.
>
> ~Anonymous DBA

If you're only limited to 3 products, then you could do something like this:

```sql
SELECT 
  c.[key]
, c.PRODUCT_1
, c.PRODUCT_2
, c.PRODUCT_3
, case 
    when charindex(convert(varchar(20), c.product_1), p.products) > 0 then 1 
    else 0 
  end bought_1
, case 
    when charindex(convert(varchar(20), c.product_2), p.products) > 0 then 1 
    else 0 
  end bought_2
, case 
    when charindex(convert(varchar(20), c.product_2), p.products) > 0 then 1 
    else 0 
  end bought_3
, p.products
FROM DB1 c
outer apply (
  select
    stuff((select '|' + convert(varchar(20),b.product) from db2 b where b.[key] = c.[key] for xml path('')),1,1,'') products
) p
```

The OUTER APPLY is like a LEFT JOIN that converts the normalized data into a pipe-delimited column named `products`.

The CASE statement in the outer query is just checking to see if the product exists in the delimited string.

[Here's the SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7fda4/2/0) for it.

Comment: Thanks for this one! And ofcourse for your advice about the structure. I will keep that in mind for further projects or maybe also for this one.